# How to get "pwsh -c {...}" to pass through the powershell command's expression result on Ubuntu?

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, powershell-core

In a PHP script on my Ubuntu 16 server I want to be able to check if Powershell has a certain module installed, which I tried to do by the line

```
pwsh -c {Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "VMware.PowerCLI"} && echo 1 || echo 0
```

But this line returns 1 even if the module isn't even installed. I suppose this is because `pwsh` returns `true` independently of the powershell command's result, to signify that the command executed properly. Is there a way I can make `pwsh` pass through the result anyway?

Comment: See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on Mac running PowerShellCore 6.0.2:

```
 $ pwsh -c 'if(-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name VMware.PowerCLI)){ exit 1 }' && echo yes || echo no
 yes
 $ pwsh -c 'if(-not (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name BadModuleName)){ exit 1 }' && echo yes || echo no
 no
```

Comment: Works. Thank you!